# Prove by universal property that epimorphism onto quotient group kills the subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, universal-property

Today I'm obsessed with universal properties and I'm trying to prove that the universal property of quotient groups implies that the subgroup is killed by the cannonical epimorphism. I hope this feeling will pass soon but I don't see it going before resolving this question, haha.

Let $G$ be a group with a normal subgroup $N\leq G$. We call a quotient such a map $\pi:G\to G/N$ (to some group denoted $G/N$) that for every map $\varphi:G\to C$ blind to the subgroup $N$ ($\ker \varphi\supseteq N$), there exists a unique $\tilde\varphi:G/N\to C$ such that $\tilde\varphi\circ\pi=\varphi$: $$\forall\varphi\in\hom(G,C):N\subseteq\ker\varphi\to\exists!\tilde{\varphi}\in\hom(G/N,C):\tilde{\varphi}\circ\pi=\varphi.$$

The previous sentece in a [commutative diagram](https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsNCxbMSwxLCJHIl0sWzIsMCwiRy9OIl0sWzIsMiwiQyJdLFswLDEsIk4iXSxbMCwyLCJcXGZvcmFsbCBcXHZhcnBoaSIsMV0sWzEsMiwiXFxleGlzdHMhXFx0aWxkZVxcdmFycGhpIiwxLHsic3R5bGUiOnsiYm9keSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiZGFzaGVkIn19fV0sWzAsMSwiXFxwaSIsMV0sWzMsMCwiIiwxLHsic3R5bGUiOnsidGFpbCI6eyJuYW1lIjoiaG9vayIsInNpZGUiOiJ0b3AifX19XSxbMywxLCIhMCIsMCx7ImN1cnZlIjotMn1dLFszLDIsIjAiLDIseyJjdXJ2ZSI6Mn1dXQ==):
[image]

I want to prove that the map $N\to G/N$ here (which I denoted by "!0") is the zero map, i.e. that $\forall n\in N:\pi(n)=e_{G/N}$.

(Yes, here $G/N$ is not the classical quotient, but any group satisfying the universal property)

---

The natural approach seems to take $C$ to be the classical model of the quotient, i.e. the  set $C:=\{[g]:g\in G\}$ of the cosets $[g]=\{gn:n\in N\}$ with $\varphi(g)=[g]$.

The problem is that now, for $n\in N$, I can only know something about $\tilde\varphi(\pi(n))$ - that it vanishes $\tilde\varphi(\pi(n))=\varphi(n)=[n]=e_{C}$, but nothing about the argument inside the $\tilde\varphi$ - $\pi(n)$, which I want to be $e_{G/N}$.

I'd know it vanishes too only if $\tilde\varphi$ were an injection (which I know it must be, because we took one "best" quotient possible, i.e. $\tilde\varphi$ must be an isomorphism), but I don't know how to prove that, kind of for the same reason I struggle with the above - once I have a $g\in G$ or $c\in C$, I can only go the whole way forward or the whole way backward, always skipping $G/N$.

For example, if I try to prove injectivity of $\tilde\varphi$, I take $a,b\in G/N$ with $\tilde\varphi(a)=\tilde\varphi(b)$, then by surjectivity of $\varphi$ I know $\tilde\varphi(a)=\tilde\varphi(b)=\varphi(g)=[g]$ for some $g\in G$. At this point I expect that $g$ is a common preimage of my $a$ and $b$, i.e. $\pi(g)=a=b$, but I see no way to make that connection, because the only thing I know here is that  after applying $\tilde\varphi$ I'd get the same element, $\tilde\varphi(\pi(g))=\varphi(g)=\tilde\varphi(a)=\tilde\varphi(a)$, where I'd need the hypothesis for injectivity of $\tilde\varphi$.

---

I would love a hint out of here. Not a full solution, though I expect it to be so simple as to be impossible to break down. I even [asked ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/share/9ace2e26-f520-40d9-8d52-b50e8ec210a1), which confidently used the goal in its proof lol.
I even started wondering whether my claim could be wrong, in which case I'd love a counterexample (a sample $G/N$ and $\pi:G\to G/N$). In that case, though, wouldn't it be inappropriate to call it a [universal property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Quotient_Group) of the quotient group?

Comment: Big title on your newspaper "Subgroup murder by Epimorphism ; who will stop this serial killer ?"

Comment: "It turned out to be unavoidable, experts said."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct definition of the quotient group. You missed the condition $N \subseteq \ker(\pi)$. You ask if this condition is automatic, but of course it's not. Consider $\pi := \mathrm{id} : G \to G$ otherwise. *Any* homomorphism $ G \to C$ factors uniquely through $\pi$ here. Also notice that with your incorrect definition quotient groups would not be unique.

One of the many correct definitions of the quotient group is the following: it is an initial object in the category $\mathscr{C}$ of homomorphisms $\varphi : G \to C$ with $N \subseteq \ker(\varphi)$. Keep in mind that an initial object of $\mathscr{C}$ is actually supposed to be an object in $\mathscr{C}$.

What is more interesting (and the answer is not trivial at all):

> *How to deduce $N = \ker(\pi)$ from the universal property alone*?

I leave this as an exercise ;)

Comment: Ughhh right, $\pi=\textrm{id}$ really breaks my definition. So $N\subseteq \ker\pi$ is a *condition*, not a *consequence* of the universal property. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. It is part of the universal property. In the same way as, say, bilinearity of $\otimes : M \times N \to M \otimes N$ is part of the universal property of the tensor product $M \otimes N$. Or that the map of a space $X$ to its Stone-Cech-compacitifcation $\beta X$ is continuous. etc.

Comment: What you've left as an exercise (to deduce that $N = \ker(\phi)$) from the universal property alone is precisely what I've been trying to do for hours now! It's driving me up the wall to see you leave it as an exercise haha.

Comment: Please let us know when you have found a proof :). I think nobody did so far (without cheating, that is, applying the universal property to the usual model of G/H).